# Checking each if-statement inside foreach

Tags: php, codeigniter

Why my if-statement not checking each array inside foreach ? If someone already choose same kind of value, I want to disable it from select2 value, here's my code looks like :

```
function get_status_cab()
    {
        $status=$_POST['search'];
        echo '<label for="username" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Status</label>';
        echo '<div class="col-sm-9">';
        echo '<select class="form-control select2" name="status">';
            $cek=$this->db_umum->select("SELECT id,status FROM lembaga where id='$status'");
            foreach($cek as $cek){
                $statusnya = $cek->status;
            }
            $hasil=array(
                "pusat" => "Pusat",
                "cabang" => "Cabang",   
                "unit" => "Unit",
                "proyek" => "Proyek",
                "subproyek" => "Subproyek"
            );
        foreach($hasil as $value => $label)
        {
            $no=0;
            if($value = $statusnya){
                $disable[] = "disabled='disabled'";
            }else{
                $disable[] = "";
            }
            echo "<option value='".$value."' $disable[$no]>".$label."</option>";
            $no++;
        }
        echo '</select></div><br/>'; 
    }
```

The result is if $value = $statusnya , my whole select2 will disabled. But, It is not what I want.
I want only value which is exact with $statusnya is disabled and the other is available.
Any advice ?

Comment: if($value = $statusnya){
                $disable[] = "disabled='disabled'";
            }else{
                $disable[] = "";
            }

Comment: Where is `$disable` used? And you know the difference between assignment (I.e. `=)` and equality (I.e. `==`), right?

Comment: @SamOnela using == also same, not works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using single equal(=) thats not correct you should use == for compare.

Replace this line

```
if($value = $statusnya){
```

with

```
 if($value == $statusnya){
```

also define $no outside of foreach

Example:-

```
$no=0;
foreach($hasil as $value => $label)
{                
    if($value == $statusnya){
        $disable[] = "disabled='disabled'";
    }else{
        $disable[] = "";
    }
    echo "<option value='".$value."' $disable[$no]>".$label."</option>";
    $no++;
}
```

Comment: using == also same, not works, still my whole select is disabled

Answer (score 1):

I know you already accepted an answer, and that this isn't [codereview.stackexchange.com](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) but I hope you will consider the information below.

Use the [equality operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) (I.e. `==`) instead of the [assignment operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.assignment.php) (I.e. `=`) to check if $value is *equal* to $statusnya. Also you don't need to use an array to store the *disabled* attribute (unless you need to retain information about each option being disabled later).

```
foreach($hasil as $value => $label)
{       
      $disabled = ''; // empty string -> not disabled         
     if($value == $statusnya){
           $disabled = "disabled='disabled'";
     }
     echo "<option value='".$value."' $disabled>".$label."</option>";
 }
```

The array storage requires more memory on the server compared to the string so as your page/application grows it would require more resources. Take a look at [this phpfiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/vt5u-8adr) and see [How big are arrays?](https://nikic.github.io/2011/12/12/How-big-are-PHP-arrays-really-Hint-BIG.html).

Comment: Noted man! This is what I looking for so far. The answer with differences. I only know how to code, dont know it is good for future development or not.

Answer (score 0):

```
$disable = arrary();
foreach($hasil as $value => $label)
        {
            $no=0;
            if($value = $statusnya){
                $disable[$no] = "disabled='disabled'";
            }else{
                $disable[] = "";
            }
            echo "<option value='".$value."' $disable[$no]>".$label."</option>";
            $no++;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$disable = array();
foreach($hasil as $value => $label)
{
    $no=0;
    if($value == $statusnya){
        $disable[$no] = "disabled='disabled'";
    }else{
        $disable[] = "";
    }
    echo "<option value='".$value."' $disable[$no]>".$label."</option>";
    $no++;
}
```